Raspberry Pi 4B Fails to Boot with Neo-7M GPS Module Connected to UART (ttyAMA0)
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 20.04 server mode, connected to a Neo-7M GPS module (link to product). The connections are as follows:
5V (GPS) to 5V (Raspberry Pi)
GND to GND
TX (GPS) to RX (Raspberry Pi, ttyAMA0)
To set up the GPS, I made the necessary changes to the configuration files, such as enabling the UART in:
/boot/config.txt
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1

/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
elevator=deadline net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=IN

/boot/firmware/config.txt
# Please DO NOT modify this file; if you need to modify the boot config, the
# "usercfg.txt" file is the place to include user changes. Please refer to
# the README file for a description of the various configuration files on
# the boot partition.

# The unusual ordering below is deliberate; older firmwares (in particular the
# version initially shipped with bionic) don't understand the conditional
# [sections] below and simply ignore them. The Pi4 doesn't boot at all with
# firmwares this old so it's safe to place at the top. Of the Pi2 and Pi3, the
# Pi3 uboot happens to work happily on the Pi2, so it needs to go at the bottom
# to support old firmwares.

[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin

[pi2]
kernel=uboot_rpi_2.bin

[pi3]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin

[pi0]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin

[all]
device_tree_address=0x03000000

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't 
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=dwc2

[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]

# The following settings are "defaults" expected to be overridden by the
# included configuration. The only reason they are included is, again, to
# support old firmwares which don't understand the "include" command.

enable_uart=1
cmdline=cmdline.txt

include syscfg.txt
include usercfg.txt

dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

Issue:
When the GPS module is connected to the Raspberry Pi via RX/TX before booting, the Pi fails to boot and gets stuck. However, if I disconnect the RX/TX wires, the Pi boots normally. Once booted, reconnecting the GPS module works fine, and data is received as expected.
Question:
Is there a way to ensure the Raspberry Pi boots properly without needing to disconnect the GPS module every time?
Are there any additional settings or changes required to avoid this boot conflict while maintaining GPS functionality?
